# How to add jquery click event to gRaphael graphics?

Tags: jquery, graphael

I made a chart using g.Raphael:

```
$(function(){
    var r = Raphael("pieChart"),
            pie = r.piechart(320, 240, 100, [55, 20, 13, 32, 5, 1, 2, 10]);

            r.text(320, 100, "Interactive Pie Chart").attr({ font: "20px sans-serif" });
            $(pie.sector).click(function(){
                alert('hi');//not work!
            })

})
```

Later I added the click event to pie.sector, but my event is not work... any one know the right way to handle gRaphael with jQuery?

Answer (score 4):

Here you go

Iterate over you pie slices and add click handler to them

```
for(var index_i=0;index_i < pie.covers.items.length;index_i++){
    pie.covers.items[index_i].click(clickSomeSlice);
}


var clickSomeSlice = function () {
    alert("clicked on\t"+this.label[1].attrs.text);
};
```

[Here a complete jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/vedmack/kqSEw/62/)

Answer (score 0):

Just select the pie

```
$(pie).click(function(){
    alert('hi');
})
```